# Getting unique values from a column

Tags: excel, vba

The task at hand is to search in column A to see what values I have (they are in form of letters) and paste for each unique entry, its value once in another column.

Here is a visual explanation:

[image: Visual example of the table and action I need]

What I came up with was to create a For loop that iritiates through column A and created a conditional that if it found a certain value then it would insert the value in the range. Here is the code:

```
For i = 1 to 26

if cells(i,26).value= "A" Then

Range ("C1")= "A"

Elseif cells(i,26).value = "B" then
Range ("C2").value = "B"
ElseIf (i,26).value = "C" then 
Range ("C3").value = "C"
EndIf
Next i
end sub
```

I want to cut this process short as my data set is really big with lots of company names. Any recommendations? I believe there has to be a way of knowing the values without having to look at all the values yourself.

Comment: Perhaps use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to get the unique letters in column A, then output the corresponding company names in column C based on the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: Does this amount to a list of unique values? If so you could use advanced filter or copy and remove duplicates.

Comment: Do you have `UNIQUE` formula? VBA may be overkill

Comment: If this is a one-off ADHOC need there are easier ways. `UNIQUE` formula is ideal. If you don't have that formula then you can also make a Pivot Table and add company name to the rows which will also provide you with the unique list. Or, you can manually follow the steps in macro (copy column, remove duplicates) etc

Comment: Excel is not a Database. If it were, this would be a simple `SELECT UNIQUE` away.

Comment: lol useful @HackSlash Maybe its Presto and only a `SELECT DISTINCT` away ;P

Comment: You can also use a pivot table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly different version of using `.RemoveDuplicates` which also removes blank cells.

You can also do this without VBA. Just copy the desired column to another and use <kbd>Remove Duplicates</kbd> under <kbd>Data</kbd> tab.

```
Sub Unique_Values()

   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    'Getting all the values in column A (except header)
    'Copying them into cell C2 and below
    ws.Range("A2", Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Copy Range("C2")
    
    'setting the header for the column C
    ws.Range("C1").Value = "What companies are in Column A?"
    
    'Removing duplicates and blanks from column C
    With ws.Range("$C$2", Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
       On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Although I agree with the coding convention used in the other answer, I think it is over-complicating the problem a little bit that would cause confusion for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

If the goal is to just get a unique list of values found in `Column A` output to `Column C` you can use the below macro. This is really just recreating the steps of one method you would manually take to find unique values. Not the most sophisticated solution, but it works

1. Create a copy of your column with company names (using last available column in sheet)
2. De-dup the helper column
3. Copy the de-duped column to destination
4. Delete the helper column

*Assumes the last column on worksheet is not used*

---

```
Sub Unique()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long

'Determine Range Size
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).Column

'Copy Company Names To Helper Column/Remove Duplicates
ws.Range("A2:A" & lr).Copy ws.Cells(1, lc)
ws.Columns(lc).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lc).End(xlUp).Row

'Output Unique Values From Helper Column
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Copy
ws.Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Delete Helper Column
ws.Columns(lc).Delete

End Sub
```

---

*Note my comment on post. VBA may not be needed here at all*

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think both answers so far will give you exactly what you want, and perhaps could be simplified even further?

```
Sub GetUniqueQuick()
Dim LastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")    
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the dynamic features of MS 365 you can simply apply the **worksheet function** `UNIQUE()` over a given range, e.g.

```
= UNIQUE(A2:A100)
```

or integrate it in a user defined function

```
Function GetCompanies(rng As Range)
    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function    ' allow only one column
    GetCompanies = Application.Unique(rng)         ' return function result as 2-dim array
End Function
```

As empty cells result in pseudo-uniques with a `0` output, you could call them in formula with an added cosmetical blank string :

```
=GetCompanies(A2:A100)&""
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!